# Why is my cache raising after each day?

Tags: android, caching, memory-management

I have an android app and its cache is raising from time to time.
I think that the reason for this could be probably that I have an endles running background service which always request my position. 
I also have a database which is always open but I don´t think that this could be a problem. 
The next thing I was thinking about was this code:

```
ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```